# How to get reference to object you're calling in method?

Tags: ruby, class

I am trying to create a method for objects that I create. In this case it's an extension of the Array class. The method below, `my_uniq`, works. When I call `puts [1, 1, 2, 6, 8, 8, 9].my_uniq.to_s` it outputs to `[1, 2, 6, 8]`.

In a similar manner, in `median`, I'm trying to get the reference of the object itself and then manipulate that data. So far I can only think of using the `map` function to assign a variable `arr` as an array to manipulate that data from.

**Is there any method that you can call that gets the reference to what you're trying to manipulate?** Example pseudo-code that I could replace `arr = map {|n| n}` with something like: `arr = self`.

```
class Array
  def my_uniq
    hash = {}
    each do |num|
      hash[num] = 0;
    end
    hash.keys
  end
end

class Array
  def median
    arr = map {|n| n}
    puts arr.to_s
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dup`

```
class Array
  def new_self
    dup
  end

  def plus_one
    arr = dup
    arr.map! { |i| i + 1 }
  end

  def plus_one!
    arr = self
    arr.map! { |i| i + 1 }
  end
end

array = [1, 3, 5]
array.new_self # => [1, 3, 5]
array.plus_one # => [2, 4, 6]
array # => [1, 3, 5]
array.plus_one! # => [2, 4, 6]
array # => [2, 4, 6]
```

`dup` makes a copy of the object, making it a safer choice if you need to manipulate data without mutating the original object. You could use `self` i.e. `arr = self`, but anything you do that changes `arr` will also change the value of `self`. It's a good idea to just use `dup`.

If you do want to manipulate and change the original object, then you can use `self` instead of `dup`, but you should make it a "bang" `!` method. It is a convention in ruby to put a bang `!` at the end of a method name if it mutates the receiving object. This is particularly important if other developers might use your code. Most Ruby developers would be very surprised if a non-bang method mutated the receiving object.

Comment: What if we have internal arrays in `self`?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Array
  def median
    arr = self
    puts arr.to_s
  end
end
```

[1,2,3].median # => [1,2,3]

Comment: The problem with this answer is it turns the method into a destructive method. It mutates `self` if you were to do any operations to `arr`

Comment: Yeah, but nothing destructive happening as per the asked question. If the function changes `self` then your answer `dup` is more appropriate.

Comment: I thought I tried self and it didn't work. I must have been out in space!

Comment: @Scott use `self` only if you want to mutate the original object. If you're going to do any operations to the array in the method body it will permanently mutate `self` as well. Otherwise `dup` is safer. To keep with Ruby idioms, you should use `dup` in your `median` method and define a `median!` that uses `self`. If anyone else were to use your method they might not realize `median` is destructive and it could cause unexpected results. Just my two cents. If you want mutation though then `self` is what you're looking for

Comment: @m.simonborg Thanks, that's gonna help save me some headaches in the near future!

Comment: @archana from the original question: `In a similar manner, in median, I'm trying to get the reference of the object itself and then manipulate that data. So far I can only think of using the map function to assign a variable arr as an array to manipulate that data from.` OP says clearly that the intent is to manipulate the data. If OP is going to select your answer it should be updated IMO to make clear that using `self` will be destructive to the original object